# Value AutoComplete

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to know how to use the value typed in the autocomplete field in my Controller, even though it is null and not a registered vehicle in the BD.

```
<p:outputLabel value="Veículo: " style="padding-right: 30px"/>
                    <p:autoComplete id="veiculo" dropdown="true" 
                        label="Veículo" required="false" placeholder="Todos" 
                        readonly="#{portariaController.tipoVeiculo == 'SEM_PLACA' || portariaController.tipoVeiculo == 'SEM_VEICULO'}"
                        value="#{portariaController.veiculo}" 
                        completeMethod="#{veiculoController.completeVeiculos}" 
                        maxResults="10" var="v" itemLabel="#{v.placa}" 
                        converter="#{entityConverter}" itemValue="#{v}" forceSelection="false" >
                        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update=":formPrincipal:pnlVeiculo" />
                        <p:ajax event="change" update=":formPrincipal:edit"/>
                    </p:autoComplete>
```

Comment: Create an entity for it and just do not save it?

Comment: I just need the value typed in the autocomplete to use it in my Bean.

Comment: No, since you have a converter, you need an entity